# Manipulations with raw_input

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have 5 lists of 5 integers.

They are the number of meteors observed over a number of hours.

```
# Nights = [11pm,12pm,1am,2am,3am]
mon = [2,4,1,3,2]
tue = [3,2,4,3,3]
wed = [1,2,1,1,1]
thu = [4,3,2,3,4]
fri = [2,1,2,1,1]
```

I want to use raw_input to ask me for a night and a time and then it will return the value to me.

```
night = raw_input('Which night? mon,tue,wed,thu or fri. ')
time = raw_input('Which time? t11,t12,t01,t02 or t03. ')
t11,t12,t01,t02,t03 = 0,1,2,3,4
print night[time]
```

The problem here is that the 'night' raw_input is a string and can't be used for night[time]

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Dictionaries would make this easier: `data = {'mon': {'t11': 2, ...}, ...}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the meteor occurrences corresponding to the days as a dictionary, like this

```
occurrences = dict(
    mon = [2, 4, 1, 3, 2],
    tue = [3, 2, 4, 3, 3],
    wed = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    thu = [4, 3, 2, 3, 4],
    fri = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
)
```

The same way you can store the times also as a dictionary

```
times = dict(
    t11 = 0
    t12 = 1,
    t01 = 2,
    t02 = 3,
    t03 = 4
)
```

Now, simply get the index from the `times` and occurrences from `occurrences` and display them, like this

```
night = raw_input('Which night? mon,tue,wed,thu or fri. ')
time = raw_input('Which time? t11,t12,t01,t02 or t03. ')
print occurrences[night][times[time]]
```

Comment: You'll need to map the `time` string into `times` too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops, sorry. Fixed that :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've upvoted both of you... but I think this one's not only 2 minutes earlier, but also easier syntax wise for the OP to adapt :)

Comment: @JonClements: Hah, but I added more options still! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters ooo... liking the namedtuple idea there... but can't upvote again, so nah nah de nah nah :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Me upvotes it for the `_asdict`. Never seen it before. You have a typo in the tuesday entry.

Comment: @JonClements Don't worry, I got it :) - the `_asdict` is new to me too. I think that it not meant for public use.

Comment: @JonClements: `namedtuple` makes for a much more readable alternative to a dictionary here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid nope it *is meant* for public use. The elements of a named tuple aren't allowed to start with an underscore, and to avoid a conflict between namedtuple's methods and those elements, its methods are `_method`... (eg: you can have a `asdict` named element, and still access `_asdict` as the method)...

Answer (score 4):

`night` is just a string, not the variable with the same name. Put those lists in a dictionary instead:

```
nights = {
    'mon': [2,4,1,3,2],
    'tue': [3,2,4,3,3],
    'wed': [1,2,1,1,1],
    'thu': [4,3,2,3,4],
    'fri': [2,1,2,1,1],
}
```

Now you can map into *that* to get each night. You'll also need a similar dictionary for your times:

```
times = {'t11': 0, 't12': 1, 't01': 2, 't02': 3, 't03': 4}
```

Now you can use these maps to map into the `nights` structure:

```
night = raw_input('Which night? mon,tue,wed,thu or fri. ')
time = raw_input('Which time? t11,t12,t01,t02 or t03. ')
print nights[night][times[time]]
```

You could also use a [`collections.namedtuple()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to give your time entries names:

```
from collections import namedtuple

NightEntry = namedtuple('NightEntry', 't11 t12 t01 t02 t03')

nights = {
    'mon': NightEntry(2,4,1,3,2),
    'tue': NightEntry(3,2,4,3,3),
    'wed': NightEntry(1,2,1,1,1),
    'thu': NightEntry(4,3,2,3,4),
    'fri': NightEntry(2,1,2,1,1),
}
```

Now each entry has attributes mapping a name to a value; `nights['mon'].t11` is the first entry in the `'mon'` night; `2`.

You can then use dynamic attribute access with [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), or make use of the [`namedtuple._asdict()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict) to make accessing attributes as a dictionary possible:

```
night = raw_input('Which night? mon,tue,wed,thu or fri. ')
time = raw_input('Which time? t11,t12,t01,t02 or t03. ')

# using getattr
print getattr(nights[night], time)

# using a dictionary
print nights[night]._asdict()[time]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
times = ['t11','t12','t01','t02','t03']
vars()[night][times.index(time)]
```

We first look up the correct variable by its string name, then we map the time name to the list index.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# Nights = [11pm,12pm,1am,2am,3am]
meteors = [[2,4,1,3,2],[3,2,4,3,3],[1,2,1,1,1],[4,3,2,3,4],[2,1,2,1,1]]

night = raw_input('Which night? mon,tue,wed,thu or fri. ')
time = raw_input('Which time? t11,t12,t01,t02 or t03. ')
night_string = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri']
time_string =['t11','t12','t01','t02','t03']
print meteors[night_string.index(night)][time_string.index(time)]
```